# Card game name search

Tags: identify-this-game

I am looking for the name of a card game I used to play at home.
Any help in finding the name of this game would be appreciated!

**SETUP:**

- It uses a card deck of 52 cards(or more than 1 deck if there are more than 4 players).
- Each player gets 7 cards.
- The rest of the cards remains face down in the middle of the table with the top card revealed next to the stack.

**HOW TO PLAY:**

- The player to the right of the dealer starts
- You start your turn by picking a card. Either from the face down stack of from the revealed stack.

  - If you pick from the revealed stack you have to take all the subsequent cards as well AND you have to use the card you picked up first to get points.
    Suppose the revealed stack looks like this:
    4 of hearts, 7 of spades, 8 of hearts, ace of clubs.

    If you want to grab the 7 of spades you have also take all the subsequent 8 of hearts and ace of clubs. This is a risk because you want to have as little as possible cards at the end of the game.

    On top of taking the extra cards you also have to get points with the first card you picked up. In this case, the 7 of spades. How you get points will become apparent later.
- After picking a card you can either get points or end your turn immediately.

  You turn ends when you add a card to the revealed stack.

  *Even after getting points you always have to end your turn with adding a card to the revealed stack. Unless you have no more cards left.*

**HOW TO GET POINTS:**
You can get points via 3 methods

1. Playing 3 cards or more with the same numeral.

   example: 5 of spades, 5 of hearts, 5 of clubs.
2. Playing 3 or more sequential cards of the same sign.

   example: 5 of spades, 6 of spades, 7 of spades
3. Adding cards to someone else' points.

   example: Player A has 3 of hearts, 4 of hearts and 5 of hearts on his board. Player B can add 2 of hearts or 6 of hearts if he has those cards.

   *Note:* *this is only possible if you have already made points via method 1 or 2. If you don't have any points on your board yet you can't use method 3 to gain points.*

**END OF GAME:**

The game ends when a player has no more cards in his hand at the end of his turn.
Then all the players count the points on their boards and the ones in their hand.

The points on the board are pluspoints, the ones in the hand or negative points.

example:

Player A has ended game and has 45 points on his board and 0 in his hand.(since he finished the game).

```
Final points = 45 points
```

Player B has 65 points on his board and 25 points in his hand.

```
Final points = 40 points
```

Thus though player B had more points on the board, Player A is still the winner.

**POINTS:**

Cards 2-9 are worth 5 points, 10-Ace are worth 10.

Example:

3 of hearts, 4 of hearts, 5 of hearts => 15 points

8 of spades, 8 of hearts, 8 of clubs => 15 points

8 of spades, 9 of spades, 10 of spades => 20 points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game you describe is a variant of [Rummy](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/rummy.html) somewhere between [500 Rummy](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/500rum.html) and [Canasta](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html)

In Canasta, A is usually worth 20 rather than 10.
And 8-K are 10 and 3-7 are 5 points, and 2s are 20.

Canasta is usually played in partnerships (2v2).

Comment: It looks very close to it, but I don't think it's Canasta. In Canasta you are not allowed to make sequences of the same suite. You can only make groups with the same number and the color is not that important (except for the 3s). 2s are wildcards. Maybe is some variant of Canasta? Maybe is something else

Comment: I did some reading and I believe the game is called 500 rummy with some slight variations on the scoring and the lay off rule. The ace is always worth 10 points and you can only lay off a single card when you already have a _set_ or _run_. We also don't use jokers. Other than that its all the same.

I'll mark you answer as the solution as it has led me to the correct variation. Thanks!

Comment: I initially wrote up an answer about 500 Rummy, but the "pull all the discards" and the scoring tiers made it seem closer to Canasta to me. But yeah, it's somewhere in between.

Comment: Edited to include 500 Rummy as well.